# Fade in/out scrolling menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've created a small script to make the menu sticky after you scroll down a bit but because I've got the bounce "bug" I would like to make it fade in/out instead so it looks smoother. The problem is that I fail making it work..

Here is the HTML:

```
<headnav>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</headnav>
```

The CSS:

```
.fixedd {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}

headnav {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 290px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99998;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-width: 1px;
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 290) {
        $('headnav').addClass('fixedd');
    } else {
        $('headnav').removeClass('fixedd');
    }
});
```

});

I've tried adding fade in/out but it doesn't seem to work.. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Theres a handy utility i use to apply css transitions and animations on the fly. 
https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a CSS transition to your fixedd class.

```
.fixedd {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

and fade out by adding the same transition to the headnav class

```
headnav {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like anything change. Thanks though